# Can I make ravioli dough with only all-purpose flour or do I NEED semolina flour?

Tags: substitutions, pasta, flour, ravioli

This is the exact recipe I'm talking about: https://selfproclaimedfoodie.com/butternut-squash-ravioli/

I'm not a very strong cook, I'm only 22 and have very little experience. I've got working with yeast down pact so I thought I'd try and make a pasta dish and I wanted to try this recipe but I can't find semolina flour ANYWHERE at my local stores. I really don't want to pay for special flour and have it shipped to my house.

Can I use more all-purpose flour in its place? What will happen if I don't use it? Will it ruin my dinner? Should I just find another recipe?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice, Margaret. When you ask "Should I just find another recipe?", are you asking about just the pasta portion of the recipe, or are you concerned that the pasta component is so finely tuned to the rest of the linked recipe that using a different recipe for the pasta component (that works fine in other applications) will produce dramatically worse results? If you mean to ask the second question, you may get better answers for that part of your question if you ask a separate question. ("When and how should fresh pasta be adjusted for the filling used in filled pastas?")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pasta can be made from many types of flour.  Often, this is predicated on style of pasta or the dish.  100% AP flour will be just fine for your ravioli. I use it often when making fresh pasta.

Substituting the AP flour for the semolina might impact the hydration.  I would hold off on the water at first.  If the dough feels too dry, add water a tablespoon at a time.  Getting the correct hydration comes with practice when making pasta.

Comment: In fact, the recipe linked to mentions others using only AP flour and why the author prefers mixing semolina with AP.